# How to fix 404 error when path exists in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, custom-error-pages

The route exists, check the route:list, clean the route cache, but I still get the 404 error.

[404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE3bF.png)

This is the route:

```
Route::get('cuentas/solicitudes',[CuentasController::class, 'solicitudes'])->middleware('auth.admin')->name('cuentas.solicitudes');
```

Function in controller:

```
public function solicitudes(Request $request){
        $agente = auth()->user()->agente;
        $cedula = $request->get('cedula');
            $cuentas = Cuenta::orderBy('cuentas.numero_cuenta', 'desc')
            ->join('clientes', 'clientes.id_cliente','=', 'cuentas.id_cliente')
            ->where('clientes.cedula', 'LIKE', "%$cedula%")
            ->where('estado_solicitud', false)
            ->paginate(10);

        return view('cuentas.solicitudes', compact('cuentas'));
    }
```

This is in the nav template:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('cuentas.solicitudes') }}">Solicitudes</a></li>
```

Comment: Note that the order in which you define routes is important. Are there any other routes that have `cuentas/solicitudes` as part of their URL?

Comment: You might have a caching issue. Try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Or perhaps a wildcard such as `cuentas/{param}` or just `{param}` as the full route above the route you've shown us?

Comment: or your middleware is modified in a way to show a 404 on failure. All and all, you need to add more debug details to your question that only you can do. try all of the above suggestions.

Comment: I don't have any other route that is related to this one, I already did the `php artisan route:clear` and it doesn't receive any parameters.

Comment: For some reason I changed the `cuentas/solicitudes` to `solicitudes` and it works fine. Do you have any idea what was causing the error?